# How a fish sonar is built and signals from sensors processed?

Tags: ultrasound, sonar

How a fish sonar is built and signals from sensors processed ?

There are $50 fish wireless sonars on the market.

I would to buy one but need to know how it works, what is a number of sensors and if sensors rotate, at what frequency and what is a load of data to be processed real-time.

No such data come with fish sonar on a market.

Can you help ?

Comment: You will have to link us to such a device, and a datasheet

Comment: If you are fishing, you attach it to your boat according to the instruction sheet, turn it on, and it shows you where stuff is.  That's "how it works" from that perspective.  You need to tell us _why_ you need to know how it works in more depth, perhaps even what you're going to be using it for.  The people will know which part of the totally open-ended "how it works" question needs to be answered.

Comment: there are no details like number of sensors, if rotated or not etc.

https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-fish-sonar.html?catId=0&initiative_id=SB_20230522025314&SearchText=fish+sonar&spm=a2g0o.home.1000002.0

"    Power Source: No. 7 Battery
    Language: English
    Detecting Range: 0.6-73 Meter
    Power Input: DC 10-18V
    Sonar Frequency: Wireless: 125Khz
    Sonar Coverage: 90-degree
    Origin: Mainland China
    Material: Plastic
    Model: D / D-T (optional)
    Dimension: 7.8 * 5.5cm / 3.1 * 2.2in
    Weight: 45g / 1.6oz

Comment: @TimWescott I need to know number of sensors in such fish sonar, if rotating or not, to know resolution, number of beams and data load to get it connected to my PC
Aliexpress is full of fish sonars and it makes me hard to make the right decision which one to buy.
I plan to start tests with acoustic sensors used for car parking.
Not sure if moving from outdoor to water environment, ultrasounds can still work
and what data can be read from LED display.